# How to retrieve 'Digits' parameter from call log?

Tags: twilio

In the twilio web interface, when I look at a specific call, I can see all the associated requests under the request inspector.  Is there any way to retrieve this data via the REST API?

Specifically, I'm trying to retrieve the 'Digits' parameter to see what a caller dialed in response to a `<gather>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

There is currently no way to download the entire HTTP request/response using the API.  This is something you would have to log yourself as the call is occuring.  If you save the call sid at the same time as the Digits, that would allow you to tie those digits back to a specific call.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Devin.  The method you described is how we currently log this data  in our Salesforce app.   Since Salesforce has pretty tight data storage limits, I was hoping I could stop logging calls there, and just retrieve the info when needed from the Twilio API.  I guess I will need to start logging in an external DB instead.  Is there any plan to add this feature in the future?  It doesnt seem like it should be such a big deal to include the full request URL(s) in the call response.  Thanks anyway!